# How would I call a combination of specific data and procedure used to analyze the data?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

So I have a number of different sets of data, let's call them A, B, C, D etc. I also have a number of analysis methods for the data. Let's call them 1, 2, 3 etc.

I'm looking for a word or a phrase, if no single word exists, that can be used to explain the combination of the data and analysis method. So I'd have let's say α=(A,1), β=(A,2), γ=(B,3). What name would I use for the α, β or γ?

I was initially thinking of just using "dataset", but with that word, people tend to confuse A, B, C and α, β, γ.

**Edit**

OK, I see that people are taking interest, but I'm nor 100% sure if I explained clearly what I'm trying to do. So here's a couple of examples:
[image: Table example]

Here's another example:

> After comparison of results, WHAT α has shown more accurate results than β, while WHAT γ has shown marginally worse results than α, but had 30% faster processing time...

Comment: [*In database theory, a **view** is the result set of a stored query on the data.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(SQL)) Would you be happy to call your "analysis methods" ***stored queries**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers While this would help CS people understand what is happening, I dont think that would make it clearer for my intended audience, which comes from medical and control systems fields.

Comment: Why would your intended audience not understand the basic figurative allusion in ***view**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't know why, but I tested this in the meantime and had negative results.

Comment: Perhaps you need to explain in more detail exactly *what you want your audience to understand* from your terminology. Is it *actually* the basic concept of what professionals in the business of data analysis & presentation would call a ***view***, or something different?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, I need them to understand exactly what I wrote: This is a set of data together with an analysis method used on the data. It also needs to be something very easy to understand, as in under 1 second of thinking. Term "view" doesn't really fit here, as I already tested.

Comment: What can I say? By any normal definition, *a set of data together with an analysis method used on the data* probably means exactly the same as *the result set of a stored query on the data*, which data analysts call a ***view***. If you don't like the standard term, or your audience don't understand it, just use your own paraphrasing.

Answer (score 1):

I would think the most applicable term is, as you have already said, "combination", since that is what you are doing with your methods 1, 2, 3 and datasets A, B, C.  You are *combining* them in different ways to get different results, and (I assume) prove the relative effectiveness of different analytical methods.

So *alpha* is the combination of dataset A and method 1, *beta* is the combination of dataset B and method 1, *gamma* the combination of B and method 3, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

When you have data, and you run it through a method, what you get is a *result*.

If the result is another dataset, you should label them *Input Dataset*, *Method*, *Result* or *Output Dataset*.

Comment: I'm aware of the result, but I need something to refer to the "word" before I actually run the data through the method and get the results.

Comment: A *transform* is where in geometry a set of points/vectors are run through an equation or matrix and a second set is generated, e.g. rotating a bunch of vertices through multiplying by a matrix.  Closest I can think of.

Comment: Otherwise use an invented term like "Dataset-method pair"